# Why is the TTakePhotoFromCameraAction.OnDidFinishTaking event not working on Android 10?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, messaging, photo

Using Delphi 10.4.2 FireMonkey, targeting Android 10 x64.

I'm trying to take a photo and save it for later processing.

First I've tried to use the built-in `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction`, but the `OnDidFinishTaking` event doesn't work (the camera screen is visible, I can take the photo and press "ok"), my program shows up, but my `TakePhotoFinishTaking()` method is not called.

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.TakePhotoFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin
  DebugEnter(0, self, 'TakePhotoFinishTaking', [Image]);
  HidePopup;
  SetBilderActions(false);
  try
    PicGrid.RowCount := PicGrid.RowCount+1;
    InsertImageItem('', Image, PicGrid.RowCount-1);
  finally
    SetBilderActions(true);
  end;
  DebugLeave(0, self, 'TakePhotoFinishTaking');
end;
```

Next I tried to use `IFMXCameraService` directly:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.btKameraClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Service: IFMXCameraService;
  Params : TParamsPhotoQuery;
begin
  DebugEnter(0, self, 'btKameraClick', [Sender]);
  if PermissionsService.IsEveryPermissionGranted([cPermissionCamera, cPermissionReadExternalStorage, cPermissionWriteExternalStorage]) then begin
    if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXCameraService, Service) then begin
      Params.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create(640, 640);
      Params.Editable           := false;
      Params.NeedSaveToAlbum    := true;
      Params.OnDidFinishTaking  := TakePhotoFinishTaking;
      Params.OnDidCancelTaking  := NIL;
      Service.TakePhoto(NIL, Params);
    end else begin
      FMX.DialogService.ASync.TDialogServiceAsync.MessageDialog('Kamerafunktion wird auf diesem Gerät nicht unterstützt!', TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK, 0)
    end;
  end else begin
    FMX.DialogService.ASync.TDialogServiceAsync.MessageDialog('Keine Kamera oder externer Speicher Rechte!', TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK, 0)
  end;
  DebugLeave(0, self, 'btKameraClick');
end;
```

Same result: I see the camera screen, take a photo, press Ok, my program comes back, but no `OnDidFinishTaking` event.

Then I've tried to intercept the messages from the Photo app:

```pascal
FFinishTakingCamPhotoId   := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromCamera,  HandleMessage);
FFinishTakingLibPhotoId   := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromLibrary, HandleMessage);
FMessageReceivedImagePath := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageReceivedImagePath,               HandleMessage);
```

All of the `subcribeToMessage()` calls are returning an ID, but `HandleMessage()` is NEVER being called for these Types.

This Message (for example) is working very well!

```pascal
FOrientationChangedId     := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TOrientationChangedMessage,              HandleMessage);
```

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.HandleMessage(const Sender: TObject; const Msg: TMessage);
var
  ImgPath : String;
begin
  DebugEnter(0, self, 'HandleMessage', [Sender, Msg]);

  {$IFDEF Android}
  if Msg is TMessageResultNotification then begin
    DebugMsg(0, 'TMessageResultNotification');
    OnActivityResult(TMessageResultNotification(Msg).RequestCode, TMessageResultNotification(Msg).ResultCode, TMessageResultNotification(Msg).Value);
  end;
  if Msg is TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromCamera then begin
    DebugMsg(0, 'TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromCamera');
    TakePhotoFinishTaking(TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromCamera(Msg).Value);
  end;
  if Msg is TMessageReceivedImagePath then begin
    DebugMsg(0, 'TMessageReceivedImagePath');
    ImgPath := TMessageReceivedImagePath(Msg).Value;
  end;
  if Msg is TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromLibrary then begin
    DebugMsg(0, 'TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromLibrary');
    TakePhotoFinishTaking(TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromLibrary(Msg).Value);
  end;
  {$ENDIF}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. This is a known problem in 10.4: [RSP-31006: ActionLIst TakePhotoFromCameraAction no Fire OnDidFinishTaking](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31006).

Comment: Do you have the Secure File Sharing option checked in the Entitlements section of the Project Options?

Comment: @Dave: Yes, i have

Comment: @Remy: thanks for editing and responding. 

I will try the (Delphi Worlds) Kastri TCamera Component next, i'm afraid it will take too long before Embarcadero fixes this. (more Customers asking fpr Android 11 support, so i have to update soon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - Problem solved.
It was an old Projekt and that was missing the option android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the application node of Androidmanifest-template.xml.

After fixing this all works fine, even the TakePhotoFromCameraAction with ObDidFinishTaking Event.

Unfortunately there is no Error or Exception where executed...

Thanks @Dave for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your app is not receiving the `TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromCamera` message is that the message is not sent if `OnDidFinishTaking` is assigned to the `Params`, as per the code in `FMX.MediaLibrary.Android`:

```
procedure TImageManagerAndroid.DidReceiveBitmap(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
var
  ImagePath: string;
  Photo: TBitmap;
  RequestCode: Integer;
begin
  if M is TMessageReceivedImagePath then
  begin
    ImagePath := TMessageReceivedImagePath(M).Value;
    RequestCode := TMessageReceivedImagePath(M).RequestCode;
    Photo := TBitmap.CreateFromFile(ImagePath);
    try
      if Assigned(FParams.OnDidFinishTaking) then
        FParams.OnDidFinishTaking(Photo)
      else
      begin
        if RequestCode = TJFMXMediaLibrary.JavaClass.ACTION_TAKE_IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA then
          TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SendMessage(Self, TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromCamera.Create(Photo));
        if RequestCode = TJFMXMediaLibrary.JavaClass.ACTION_TAKE_IMAGE_FROM_LIBRARY then
          TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SendMessage(Self, TMessageDidFinishTakingImageFromLibrary.Create(Photo));
      end;
    finally
      Photo.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The following code, which is essentially the equivalent as yours, works fine for me using Delphi 10.4.2:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Layout1: TLayout;
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCameraPermissions: TArray<string>;
    procedure CameraDidFinishTakingHandler(Image: TBitmap);
    procedure TakePhoto;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  System.Permissions,
  FMX.Platform.Android,
  FMX.MediaLibrary, FMX.Platform;

const
  cPermissionCamera = 'android.permission.CAMERA';
  cPermissionReadExternalStorage = 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
  cPermissionWriteExternalStorage = 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FCameraPermissions := [cPermissionReadExternalStorage, cPermissionWriteExternalStorage, cPermissionCamera];
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions(FCameraPermissions,
    procedure(const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>)
    begin
      if PermissionsService.IsEveryPermissionGranted(FCameraPermissions) then
        TakePhoto;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.TakePhoto;
var
  LCameraService: IFMXCameraService;
  LParams: TParamsPhotoQuery;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXCameraService, LCameraService) then
  begin
    LParams.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create(640, 640);
    LParams.Editable := False;
    LParams.NeedSaveToAlbum := True;
    LParams.OnDidFinishTaking := CameraDidFinishTakingHandler;
    LParams.OnDidCancelTaking := nil;
    LCameraService.TakePhoto(nil, LParams);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CameraDidFinishTakingHandler(Image: TBitmap);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Hi Dave,
you are right - this code (in a new appp) works.

I'll try to figure out why it's not working in MY app - because gererally i'm doing the same but CameraDidFinishTakingHandler is not called...

Comment: After investigating further i've found that there is an Warning in Android Monitor just after i click "accept image" in Photo Screen. **Could not return photo from camera to native side. Could not find the photo file.** It seems that  this belongs to **com.embarcadero.firemonkey.medialibrary.FMXMediaLibrary.handleCameraPhoto()**, Procedure **private void handleCameraPhoto()**. Unfortunately i'm not able to find then Source for this Library...
I will investigate further...

Comment: That routine is in the Java source for FMX, in `source\rtl\androiddex\java\fmx\src\com\embarcadero\firemonkey\medialibrary\FMXMediaLibrary.java`. Presumably it has failed to save the image to file, so there might be messages before it to indicate why